# Как оптимизировать код? JS

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Всем привет!
Непосредственно сам код:

```
window.onload = function(){
    setTimeout(function () {
        refresh('.fadeUp');
        refresh('.slideDown');
        refresh('.run-text');
        window.onresize = function(){
            refresh('.fadeUp');
            refresh('.slideDown');
            refresh('.run-text');
        }
        window.onscroll = function(){
            refresh('.fadeUp');
            refresh('.slideDown');
            refresh('.run-text');
        }
    }, 1500);
}
```

События **onresize** и **onscroll** должны добавляться только после завершения события **onload**.
С задержкой в **1500** миллисекунд. Далее повторяются одни и те же три строчки вызова **refresh**. Для трех разных событий, как оптимизировать данный участок кода?
Всем, спасибо!

Comment: Ну вынесите 3 refresh в отдельную функцию

Comment: On scroll и on resize по сути одна и та же функция

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я бы сделал так

```
function refreshAll(){
            refresh('.fadeUp');
            refresh('.slideDown');
            refresh('.run-text');
        }

window.onload = function(){
    setTimeout(function () {
        refreshAll();
        window.onresize = refreshAll;
        window.onscroll = refreshAll;
    }, 1500);
}
```

Но это не оптимизация, а рефакторинг кода. Оптимизация подразумевает какую то целевую функцию (время, память). А рефакторинг подразумевает упрощение унификация кода для дальнейшего расширения и использования